how to query azure cli that start with $
i am trying to generate azure rm parameters file , the file content should be as follow:
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "networkSecurityGroups_nsg_name": {
            "value": null
        }
    }
}

i am using this command to try to extract the parameters file :
az group export --resource-group RGname --resource-ids $nsg_id --query "{$schema: $schema, contentVersion: contentVersion, parameters: parameters}"

but the command generate the below error :
argument --query: invalid jmespath_type value: '{$schema: $schema, contentVersion: contentVersion, parameters: parameters}'
how can i get the proper value as mention command  from the command?

see: Escape characters, under "Understanding the Azure Resource Graph query language"

Have you tried using jq by any chance. @Max_il

To extract the parameters file using az group export command, it is not directly possible by using
--query argument passage.
In order to achieve it, use jq bash CLI functionality to validate the jmespath_values in the script (Json) and also to avoid escape characters conflicts.
Before working with it, firstly check if the Azure CLI environment has jq installed in it as shown in the below way.

Once it is done, use below lines of code in Az CLI to get the nsgID. Now retrieve the nsg template in the console to check if it's in proper running state and also available in the specific resource group.
nsgID=$(az resource show --resource-group Jahnavi --name newdashvm-nsg --resource-type Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups --query id --output tsv)
az group export --resource-group Jahnavi --resource-ids $nsgID


After checking it, use below command along with the jq query command to extract the parameters file from it.
az group export --resource-group Jahnavi --resource-ids $nsgID --output json | jq '{ "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#","contentVersion": "1.0.0.0", "parameters": .parameters}' > nsg_parameters.json


